# Proposing new tag: ICSS - Interoperable CSS

Tags: discussion, tags

The system prevented me from creating the new tag `ICSS` because it was deemed too similar to `icalendar`. I was advised to discuss it on meta if I think the new tag is valid.
I think adding the tag ICSS for [Interoperable CSS](https://github.com/css-modules/icss) is the right thing to do. Interoperable CSS (ICSS) is a thing now.

I chiefly watch the React and SASS/SCSS tags and noticed that the ICSS topic comes up from time to time, although most users don't know the name for the feature and refer to it as "the scss export" or something along those lines. I think the tag should be added.

The following questions should be adorned with the new tag:

- [Rollup - Allow :export statement in scss file to import in js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68588047/rollup-allow-export-statement-in-scss-file-to-import-in-js)
- [How do I import variables from scss file into a react/next.js component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68552502/how-do-i-import-variables-from-scss-file-into-a-react-next-js-component)
- [How to get SCSS variables into react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66119188/how-to-get-scss-variables-into-react)
- [How to get SCSS variables in js code (nodejs server)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66126256/how-to-get-scss-variables-in-js-code-nodejs-server)
- [SCSS :root section with :export](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68556824/scss-root-section-with-export)

Proposed Wiki excerpt:

> Interoperable CSS (ICSS) is a superset of standard CSS, adding the two pseudo-selectors :import and :export. This allows modern multi-format loaders like Webpack, JSPM and Browserify to propagate and exchange variables between different layers of the tech stack. Passing variables from CSS to JS is one of the main usecases.

Comment: What's your proposed tag wiki / excerpt?

Comment: FWIW, the similarity is due to [the tag synonym for 'icalendar'](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/icalendar/synonyms): [tag:ics], and the system prevents the pluralization of an existing tag.

Comment: I've added the tag to the first question you listed here so it'll be available now... please make sure to suggest a suitable tag wiki and excerpt as @Cerbrus has mentioned. (I've put in a place holder for now so there's something but it can certainly be expanded upon)

Answer (score 4):

ICSS is a feature of a 3rd party service/library: [CSS Modules](https://github.com/css-modules/) (note to readers: this is not some official feature of CSS published by the W3C or WHATWG or anything). I am not certain we need a separate tag for this. Do any of the other dozen or so aspects of [css-modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css-modules) have their own specialized tags?

Creating a standalone tag [icss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/icss) is just begging for people to start confusing it with an official aspect or alternative to CSS, or just mistakenly using it when they mean CSS. The fact it's part of CSS-Modules should be indicated in the tag, e.g. [css-modules-icss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css-modules-icss) or just use the existing [css-modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css-modules) instead. Why not [interoperable-css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/interoperable-css) over [icss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/icss) as well, for example?

Comment: It made sense to me although I see your point. I'm not against renaming/merging it to another tag if feedback suggests that'd be prudent. Thanks for the ping.